# How to correctly align rightBarButtonItem after dismissing a modal view controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Beginning in iOS 7, the rightBarButtonItem in my UINavigationBar gets shifted down after dismissing a modal view controller. The top screen shot shows the correct alignment. The bottom screenshot shows the wrong alignment after dismissing the modal view controller.

[image]

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
        initWithTitle:@"" 
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
        target:self
        action:@selector(didPressRightBarButtonItem)
    ];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem 
        setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shareLightFlat"]
    ];
}

- (void) didPressRightBarButtonItem
{
    [self.navigationController 
        presentViewController:[[SomePage alloc] init] 
        animated:YES 
        completion:nil];
}
```

In SomePage, I use this to dismiss itself:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this is happening, but when I tested this, it worked ok if I changed the title of the button from @"" to @" ". See if that works for you (I got somewhat different results from you -- my button was always misplaced, not only after the presentation and dismissal).

Comment: Hot diggity damn! Magical solution, but it works! It looks like a system bug that can't handle empty string.

Comment: After all these months, I've ran into the same problem again. This time, the button dropped lower for a different reason. If you have an button with an image only and you accidentally do `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = @"some text"`, it will lower the button without actually setting the text. That's Just a friendly reminder.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to use **initWithTitle: @ ""**

try this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *editBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(myAction:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[editBarButton];
```

Comment: This works better than rdelmar's answer. Setting the title to a single space will create a small shift.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a UIBarButtonItemStyleDone style button then setting the image. I think it would work better to go with:

```
UIButton * aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
... // Set frame and addTarget
[aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shareLightFlat"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem * editBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
```

I have not seen any related issues with iOS7.

Comment: I use the "Done" style to get a darker background in iOS 6. In iOS 7, the style is ignored because buttons don't have styling in iOS 7.